# Cassandra version differences

Tags: cassandra, cql

I started reading Cassandra the definitive guide, which is based on Cassandra 0.7. Now, I'm trying to experiment with Cassandra 2.1.5 and it seems that there's a lot of differences which is really confusing.

For example, I see that in 0.7 version CQL did not exist. On the other hand, data model seems quite different. You can now define a schema with CQL, while in version 0.7 there was no schema.

Can anyone shortly explain the differences, especially about the data model?

I understand that in 0.7 version the idea was about different length rows, that is, rows that have different number of columns. But now I understand that each column is actually a field that contains a number of parameters, so you can have as much fields as you want within the same row (same key).

Can someone summarize the differences? Maybe I did not understand correctly.

Comment: In this answer I discuss some of the ways in which CQL rows are handled at the storage level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114854/cassandra-storage-internal/

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 Could you please explain was it like this in the earlier versions? That is what confused me the most...

Comment: I would compare your confusion with reading the Mac SE User Manual for tips on how to use your shiny new gold 2015 Macbook. You might have better luck reading the 2.1 docs http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/ and getting help on the user@ mailing list and IRC - bottom of http://cassandra.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important point to consider, is that the underlying storage model remains the same.  CQL is simply an abstraction layer on top of that model, to make it easier to work with and model your data.  DataStax MVP John Berryman has a great article on this: [Understanding How CQL3 Maps to Cassandra’s Internal Data Structure](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/07/24/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/)

In this article, Berryman observes that:

- The value of the CQL primary key is used internally as the row key (which in the new CQL paradigm is being called a “partition key”).
- The names of the non-primary key CQL fields are used internally as columns names. The values of the non-primary key CQL fields are then internally stored as the corresponding column values.

Additionally, he outlines the benefits of using the CQL-based approach:

- It provides fast look-up by partition key and efficient scans and slices by cluster key.
- It groups together related data as CQL rows. This means that you can do in one query what would otherwise take multiple queries into different column families.
- It allows for individual fields to be added, modified, and deleted independently.
- It is strictly better than the old Cassandra paradigm. Proof: you can coerce CQL Tables to behave exactly like old-style Cassandra ColumnFamilies. (See the examples here.)
- It extends easily to implementation of sets lists and maps (which are super ugly if you’re working directly in old cassandra) — but that’s for another blog post.
- The CQL protocol allows for asynchronous communication as compared with the synchronous, call-response communication required by Thrift. As a result, CQL is capable of being much faster and less resource intensive than Thrift – especially when using single threaded clients.

> can have as much fields as you want within the same row (same key).

Actually, there is a hard limit of about 2 billion columns per partition (rowkey).